# How can I change the power related settings (suspend, hibernate...) with the command line only?

Tags: multiple-monitors, suspend, power-management, laptop, i3-wm

I am using Ubuntu 18.04 with i3wm, so I don't have access to the settings menu from Gnome.

I am using a laptop in a dock with two external monitors hooked up to it. The lid is closed while it's in the dock.

The problem is that after a while, the laptop goes to sleep when not in use. It happens whether the lid is kept open or kept closed.

I'd like to change that for it to never go asleep when it's on AC power and has external monitors regardless of whether the lid is open or closed.

Which config file do I need to edit?

Comment: If you run `gnome-control-center` or `gnome-settings-daemon` the Gnome settings should be available. I used to do that with openbox desktop, works just fine.  Otherwise, everything you do will need sudo access.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not using the I3 Windowing Manager but these settings should work for you just as they do with Unity and Gnome Desktop. First discover the current settings:

```
$ gsettings get org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power sleep-inactive-ac-timeout
0

$ gsettings get org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power sleep-inactive-ac-type
'suspend'
```

If your first setting is not `0` set it to zero so inactivity is not measured:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power sleep-inactive-ac-timeout 0
```

If your second setting reads 'suspend' set it to 'nothing':

```
gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power sleep-inactive-ac-type 'nothing'
```

---

To list all settings use:

```
$ gsettings list-recursively | grep -E 'sleep|suspend*'
org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power sleep-inactive-ac-timeout 0
org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power power-button-action 'suspend'
org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power critical-battery-action 'suspend'
org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power lid-close-suspend-with-external-monitor true
org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power sleep-inactive-ac-type 'nothing'
org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power button-suspend 'suspend'
org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power button-sleep 'suspend'
org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power sleep-inactive-battery-timeout 0
org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power lid-close-ac-action 'suspend'
org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power sleep-inactive-battery-type 'suspend'
org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power lid-close-battery-action 'suspend'
org.gnome.desktop.screensaver ubuntu-lock-on-suspend true
org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power sleep-inactive-ac-timeout 0
org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power power-button-action 'suspend'
org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power critical-battery-action 'suspend'
org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power lid-close-suspend-with-external-monitor true
org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power sleep-inactive-ac-type 'nothing'
org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power button-suspend 'suspend'
org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power button-sleep 'suspend'
org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power sleep-inactive-battery-timeout 0
org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power lid-close-ac-action 'suspend'
org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power sleep-inactive-battery-type 'suspend'
org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power lid-close-battery-action 'suspend'
```

Comment: Thank you, will see how it goes over the next few days.

Comment: It didn't work, the machine is still suspending itself after a while.

Comment: There are more settings I'll add after work. Did you get the existing settings before setting to confirm they were active?

Comment: Yes I did, and they were active. The timeout was `4800`, I set it to `0`; and the type was `'suspend'`, I set it to `'nothing'`. After the machine suspended again to see if they got overwritten somehow but they weren't and are still `0` and `'nothing'`.

Comment: @springloaded Updated answer with all possible options. Please run the same command on your system and see if there are extras.

Comment: Everything looks like it should there, anything to do with ac is set to 0 or 'nothing'. That is so puzzling.